# Rails apache pdf permissions 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise, ftp, permissions

I'm going crazy trying to understand why I get a 401 (unauthorized) when trying to access pdf files. I have a project serving pdf documents and videos. Both are stored in two folders, owned by a special group (that i named ftp-users), where i can upload files via ftp but cannot be accessed directly.

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 accademiadipolizia ftp-users 4096 Feb 24  2015 documents/
drwxr-xr-x  2 accademiadipolizia ftp-users 4096 Aug 11  2015 videos/
```

Files (documents and videos) are served with rails actions, protected with a filter that check if the user is a registered user (permissions are set with devise).

This is the action relative to pdf files

```
  def documents
    filename = File.join([Rails.root, "private", "documents", params[:path]]) + ".pdf"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf{
        send_file filename
      }
    end
  end
```

where the "private" folder is a symbolic link to the documents folder.

and the relative route to serve the action:

```
resources :subjects do
    get 'page', on: :member
  end
  get 'documents/*path', to: "subjects#documents"
```

whereas the one for videos is slightly different:

```
resources :lessons, only: :show do
    member do
      get 'video'
    end
```

The problem is that for the videos (same similar action, same folder and files permissions, same devise filter, but a different route) everything is working fine, while for documents i always get a 401.

this is the logtrace of the server

```
I, [2016-03-16T13:03:45.580929 #32592]  INFO -- : Processing by SubjectsController#documents as PDF
I, [2016-03-16T13:03:45.581215 #32592]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"path"=>"castellucci/ordinamento-della-polizia-municipale"}
I, [2016-03-16T13:03:45.583038 #32592]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

where is the problem?

EDIT:

actually the way of serving files is different: in the case of videos, the link to the video is a field of the object with the video link (so the route is a member of the object and i think devise doesn't have problems with the filter), whereas the link to the document is a direct link to the file, so in this case it's apache to serve the file... how can i find a workaround to it?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with Apache, it is **Rails** that returns the 401 error (otherwise it would not appear in the rails log). I would try to really get assured that the error is not devise-related. For example, could you add a `Rails.logger.info "sending file: #{filename}"` just before the `respond_to` block in the `documents` controller action? If devise filter stopped you, nothing would get written to the log and you would get the 401 error.

Comment: You're perfectly right, it was a silly consideration, as it's Rails who's answering and not Apache directly. 
This is what is printed:


RAIL SENDING FILE /var/www/police_production/releases/20160316141840/private/documents/ercolanoni/diritto-amministrativo.pdf

the problem is that the file now is being downloaded ... no more 401, but nothing has changed... just added a Logger.info as you advised...

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you restarted the server in between retries? Well, at least it works now :)

Comment: hahaha well actually i re-deployed a couple of times to add these lines... but... that's even more frustrating... thank you for now btw

Answer (score 0):

After just adding a

```
Rails.logger.info "#{filename}"
```

as suggested by @BoraMa and rededploying the application with capistrano (hence restarting the server), made things work again in the proper way. 
Not properly a true solution, but just keep track of strange behaviours. 
If anybody has any clue about what happened feel free to write it down.